# Javascript help on dynamically creating html elements and populating the element onto the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So in the script tag here I have an array myArr that is printed into p tag in the html:

```
<html>
  <body>
<h1>Header 1</h1>
<div>
  <p id="test"></p>
</div>
</body>
 </html> 
<script> 
var myArr = ["abc", 123, "test"];
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = myArr; 
</script>
```

All that works and is good. So, I have a couple of questions about this, as I'm pretty new to javascript.

I know how to iterate through the array and print out each element within the script tag. But how would I be able to display it into the html? Is there a way to dynamically create the p tags with the element from the array as the contents?

And would I be able to easily add stying into the dynamically created p tag?

Can this kind of thing be done using something like jquery? or another popular simple javascript library?Unfortunately, I will be unable to run a full fledged javascript framework. I am only able to run a basic library.

I attempted a try here:

```js
var my_arr = ["test", "abc", 123];
var arr_length = my_arr.length;

for (i = 0; i < arr_length; i++) {
  document.createElement("p");
  document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = arr_length;
  my_arr[i]
}
```

```html
<h2>My First Web Page</h2>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>
<div id="test">
</div>
```

Comment: Include the code in the question, please.  All relevant details(including attempts), need to be in the question itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to `forEach` over the array. Inside the callback, create a `p`, append it to the desired container, and set its `textContent` to the array element. No frameworks/libraries required:

```js
const test = document.getElementById('test');
const my_arr = ["test", "abc", 123];
my_arr.forEach((item) => {
  test.appendChild(document.createElement('p'))
    .textContent = item;
});
```

```html
<h2>My First Web Page</h2>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>
<div id="test">
</div>
```

Array methods are generally preferrable to `for` loops, but if you really wanted to use a `for` loop like in your original code, you would have to set the `textContent` of the created `p` to `my_arr[i]`, in addition to appending the `p` to `test`:

```js
var my_arr = ["test", "abc", 123];
var arr_length = my_arr.length;

const test = document.getElementById('test');
for (i = 0; i < arr_length; i++) {
  const p = document.createElement("p");
  p.textContent = my_arr[i];
  test.appendChild(p);
}
```

```html
<h2>My First Web Page</h2>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>
<div id="test">
</div>
```